# How do I reconnect to OpenOffice.org once it has been closed?

Tags: c#, openoffice.org, bootstrapping, uno

Here is a sample application that creates a Window with a single Button inside. When clicked, it connects to OOo (if not already connected) and creates a text document.

This works fine unless all the documents created in OOo are closed. Then, I get a DisposedException when trying to create the next chart. This is understandable, but OOo has been closed. However, trying to reconnect at this point gives me a segfault. Is there a better way to reconnect? I am working on linux (Ubuntu).

Note: This connects properly to OOo even if OOo is not open. It's once OOo has been opened by the application, then closed that we get the error.

All you really need to look at is the Connect method. I just wrapped it in a Gtk interface for easy testing.

```
using System; 
using unoidl.com.sun.star.uno; 
using unoidl.com.sun.star.lang; 
using unoidl.com.sun.star.text; 
using unoidl.com.sun.star.frame; 
using unoidl.com.sun.star.beans; 
using Gtk; 

namespace TestOOo { 
   class MainClass { 
      static XComponentContext componentContext; 
      static XMultiServiceFactory multiServiceFactory; 
      static XComponentLoader loader; 
      static XTextDocument document; 

      public static void Main (string[] args) 
      { 
         Application.Init(); 

         Window mainWindow = new Window("Test Window"); 
         mainWindow.Visible = true; 
         mainWindow.Destroyed += delegate { Application.Quit(); }; 
         Button button = new Button(Stock.Ok); 
         button.Clicked += delegate { Connect(); }; 
         mainWindow.Add(button); 
         mainWindow.ShowAll(); 

         Application.Run(); 
      } 

      static void Connect() 
      { 
         // Connect to OOo 
         if (componentContext == null) 
            componentContext = uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap(); 

         try { 
            multiServiceFactory = 
               (XMultiServiceFactory) componentContext.getServiceManager(); 
         } catch { 
            // This is where we want to reconnect, but trying to 
            // bootstrap() again segfaults. 

            // componentContext = uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap(); 
            // multiServiceFactory = 
            //   (XMultiServiceFactory) componentContext.getServiceManager(); 
         } 

         loader = (XComponentLoader) 
            multiServiceFactory.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop"); 
         document = (XTextDocument) loader.loadComponentFromURL 
            ("private:factory/swriter", "_blank", 0, new PropertyValue[0]); 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but do you have OOo setup to exit completely once all the documents are closed?

Comment: I do (in the sense that I'm not using the Quickstarter or anything). However, I noticed that the "disposed" signal doesn't get called for the componentContext, multiServiceFactory,  or loader when I close the document. Only the "document" calls the disposed signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to figure this out, but I did find a way to hack around it:

I created a separate executable to do the generating. My main application then calls this executable, passing it the necessary parameters (just a path to the file to generate from, and the mode to generate in).

Since the crash only occurs when OOo has been closed since the application started running (and generated at least one chart), this avoids the whole issue. It's a very ugly hack, but it gets the job done.